# View() not supported in the Jupyter R kernel

Tags: r

I am using View() in Jupyter notebook, but it gives me errors:
Error in View(states): ‘View()’ not yet supported in the Jupyter R kernel. Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: `View()` usually requires an interface IDE like RStudio or RGui that can launch a separate window. Simply call object on its own line to display its content. Jupyter will format as html tables.

Answer (score 2):

`View()` is really not supported in the Jupyter R kernel yet. You can track that at [GitHub Issue #280](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/issues/280) and see that in the source code of [environment_shadow.r](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/blob/master/R/environment_shadow.r#L76-L80).

Instead, feel free to just use [`print()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/print.html), [`head()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/head.html), or maybe [`cat()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cat.html) according to your needs.